# Correct terminology to describe regular grid

Tags: georeferencing, vector-grid, terminology

What is the correct terminology to describe a regular grid of squares based on certain distance in latitude/longitude? I came up with this description:

> We used regular grid of squares measuring 10' of longitude and 6' of
> latitude (approx 12 x 11.1 km).

but I am not sure if there is any particular terminology to refer to this type of grid? I would like to use proper terminology if there is one. Or is the above description perfect?

[image]

Comment: What part of "regular grid of squares measuring 10' of longitude and 6' of latitude" are you uncomfortable with? That it's not a perfect square? You could add: regular grid of rectangle shape with cell size of 10' long and 6' lat (and extent from x to y).

Comment: If we are talking about lines of meridians and parallels, it is a cartographic grid...if not, it is a coordinate grid...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko meridians and parallels yes, but this exactly corresponds with lat/lon coordinates, so it's both then?

Comment: @Babel no, that's not my concern. I am just not proficient in the terminology, so I am asking more experienced people if it is correct. So you're saying it looks correct?

Comment: See: http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Grid_(spatial_index)#Types_of_grids and http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Grid_reference

Comment: "Correctness" is probably a bridge too far, in terms of this question not being *opinion-based*. The problem with "grid" is that there's a raster format with the same name, and "vector grid" seems inadequate and redundant, simultaneously.  "Regular rectangular partition" might be a more math-oriented descriptor.  "Fishnet" would invoke the ArcGIS command that makes the features, but is then imprecise due to that command generating both linear and areal features.  Then there's the problem that the cells in EPSG:4326 are spheroidal trapezoids. I don't think there's one correct answer here.

Comment: If the grid is the main thing so that the cell is the basic unit of your data (compare with an index for finding map sheets) it could also be called as gridded coverage or regular grid as you said it in the title of your question. See the OGC standard https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-146r6/09-146r6.html.

Comment: this is a regular cartographic grid...

Answer (score 1):

The correct terminology to describe a regular grid of squares is a *regular tessellation*.  Specifically in this case a regular tessellation of squares.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularTessellation.html